# How to set attribute value depending on a condition in angular 7

Tags: angular, conditional-statements

I have been trying to set `data-color` attribute value for my `<li>` tag depending on a condition. This is a sample array for the data i need  to check from :

```
{
Notifications: [
{
notification: "Example Notification",
notification_type: 1
},
{
notification: "Example Notification 2",
notification_type: 2
},
{
notification: "Example Notification 2",
notification_type: 3

]
}
```

This is the array i am being received i need to set data-color of my `<li>` tag depending on the notification type.

This is my `<li>` tag:

```
<li class="feed-item" *ngFor= "let notification of Notificationslist" data-content="&#xf00c;" data-color="green">
```

I need to set `data-color` to `green,red and yellow` depending on the notification type can someone help me how to achieve this. Thanks.

**Update**

I also want to set the data-content also which is a font-awesome unicode it is fine but when i try to get it through a function it just shows a string instead of the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<li [attr.data-color]="notification.color">
```

If you want to make some calculations to get the color, wrap in a method like:

```
<li [attr.data-color]="getColorForNotification(notification)">
```

```
getColorForNotification(notification: Notification) {
  switch (notification.notification_type){
    case 1:
     return 'green';
    default:
     return 'red'
  }
}
```

Comment: `<li [attr.data-color]="notification?.color">` use safe navigation operator with the above answer to avoid undefined property error

Comment: Hi i want to set the data-content as icons like the same as above but the case returns as a string if paste it inside the tag like ```data-content="&#xf00c;"``` it works fine but when i try to get it over the switch instead of showing the icon it shows a string with that value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>
```

You're better off creating a new CSS class, and styling it conditionally that way as seen above.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

```
.green-li { color: green; }
.yellow-li {color: yellow;}

<li [ngClass]="{'green-li': notification.notification_type === 1, 'yellow-li': notification.notification_type === 2 }"></li>
```

Comment: Thanks but Yevhenii's answer was the one i was looking for. Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 0):

the cleanest way would be to add a `color` attribute to the object and then just use it in your template.

e.g.: `{ notification: "Example Notification", notification_type: 1, color: 'red' },`

```
<li class="feed-item" *ngFor= "let notification of Notificationslist" data-content="&#xf00c;" [data-color]="notification.color">
```

Comment: Thanks but i didn't wanted to add column to the database.